# Can we define an uncountable sum of (not necessarily positive) real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So I've learned in my real analysis class that you can't have uncountably many positive summands "adding" to a finite sum. My question is if it's reasonable to try defining uncountably many summands (which are allowed to be negative) to get a finite sum.

In the spirit of doing things with uncountable sets, a first thought is to use $I = [0, 1)$ as an indexing set, letting $x_i = -1$ for $i \in [0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $x_i = 1$ for $i \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. Is it reasonable to then say that $\sum_{i \in I} x_i = 0$?

More generally, is there a way to do this without running into all the problems normally encountered when one is too greedy with their measures (like the Banach-Tarski paradox)?

Comment: what you're looking for is "integration"

Comment: Such a sum would be conditionally convergent, if convergent at all.

Comment: I don't think this is quite an integral. It would resemble an integral if it was something like $\sum_{i \in I} x_i dx_i$, but there is no $dx_i$ factor here.

Comment: I think this reduces back to the countable case: you are going to have to group your positive and negative terms into sub-sums that equal 0 (otherwise you will end up with either more positive terms than negative or vice versa and the sum will go to infinity) until you are left with countably many that you can sum.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Ah, you make a good point; if I instead set $I = [0, 1]$ and assigned the same values for $x_i$ as before except $x_1$ also equaled 1, I'd want this to equal 1 (as opposed to $1dx \approx 0$). I guess I'm trying to ask if there are any theorems on such "uncountable sums" (in the flavor of the rearrangement theorem for countable sums) -- I can imagine that way I decide to group them is quite important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first we need a definition. If $X$ is *any* set, "the" definition of $\sum_{x\in X}a_x$ is this:

> > **Def.** $\sum_{x\in X}a_x=s$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite set $F\subset X$ such that if $F\subset F'\subset X$ and $F'$ is finite then $|s-\sum_{x\in F'}a_x|<\epsilon$.

With that definition it's clear (and easy to prove) that if $\sum_{x\in X}a_x$ exists then $\{x:|a_x|>\epsilon\}$ is finite for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $\{x:a_x\ne0\}$ is countable. (And hence no, the example you give is not a convergent sum.)

**Note** With that definition, if $X$ is countable a convergent sum must be absolutely convergent. In fact it's easy to see that a sum converges in this sense if and only if the function $x\mapsto a_x$ is integrable with respect to  counting measure...

Comment: Cool definition, though as you've noted, that doesn't encapsulate the usual countable summation. Maybe require $X$ to be well-ordered and define the sum as the limit of partial sums?