# Why isn't this condition in the definition of decomposable measure redundant?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider this definition of a decomposable measure (from Folland Ch.3 Exercise 15):

[image: ?]

I was a bit confused about the necessity/meaning of condition 3, and just wanted to clarify: it seems that if $\mathcal F$ is countable, this is already given by the fact that $\mu$ is a measure ($E$ would be the disjoint countable union of $E \cap F_\alpha$). But if this is included to take care of the possibility that $\mathcal F$ is uncountable, what would the infinite sum mean? (If it is of any use, I did ask a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371347/can-we-define-an-uncountable-sum-of-not-necessarily-positive-real-numbers) about uncountable sums more generally a while back, but I still don't have any intuition about how they work. For example, I'm very uneasy to say that $\sum_{x \in [0, 1]} 0 = 0$ and $\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} 0 = 0$ since the additivity of measures obviously doesn't carry over.)

Comment: For the typography, use `\mathcal` instead of `\mathfrak` (well, not quite; Folland doesn't use the default mathcal font but the `eucal` package). For the sum, if we have a family $\langle a_i : i \in I\rangle$ of non-negative numbers, then $$\sum_{i \in I} a_i = \sup_{\substack{F \subset I \\ F \text{ finite}}} \sum_{i \in F} a_i\,.$$ If uncountably many $a_i$ are strictly positive, that sum is always $+\infty$. In other words, if the sum is finite, all but countably many $a_i$ are $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the question of uncountable infinite sum, note that in the case that all summands are non-negative, you may define it as the $\sup$ of all finite sub-sums.

More precisely, let $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be non-negative real numbers. We define $\sum_{i \in I} a_i$ as $$\sup\{\sum_{i\in J}a_i:J\subseteq I, \#J < \infty\}.$$
This then makes sense for any set $I$.

Note however, that this definition is not quite useful, because:

> Lemma: If the sum $\sum_{i\in I} a_i$ is finite, then the subset $\{i\in I: a_i \neq 0\}$ is countable.

It's an obvious lemma, because that subset is the union $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{i\in I: a_i \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$.

---

In other words, either there are only countably many non-zero summands, in which case it's essentially a countable sum, or the sum is simply $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any thoughts on whether this implies that condition (iii) is indeed redundant?

Comment: Since it comes before condition (iv), I'd say it is not redundant, i.e. it cannot be implied by the assumption that $\mu$ is a measure and conditions (i), (ii). Example: take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, and for every real number $x$, let $F_x$ be the singleton set $\{x\}$. The family $\mathcal{F} = (F_x)_{x\in\mathbb R}$ then satisfies conditions (i), (ii) but not (iii). I'm however not quite sure what happens when you add condition (iv) to it. If I were writing a book, I would also tend to keep this condition to ensure safety.